# Extracting an IP address from a hosts file by hostname

Tags: beginner, ruby, regex, file, ip-address

I am currently working with Vagrant for the first time, and therefore also working with Ruby for the first time. I have a specific hostname and IP address I would like set for my VM, both of which are stored in my hosts file. I would like to define the hostname in my Vagrantfile, and then have it automatically pull the matching IP address out of my hosts file for me. To do so, I have written the following code in my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  hostname = "vagrantvm"
  hostfile = "/etc/hosts"

  ip_address = File.foreach(hostfile).grep(/\b#{hostname}\b/) { |m| /^([0-9\.]*)\b.*/.match(m)[1] }.first

  config.vm.network :private_network, :ip => ip_address
  config.vm.hostname = hostname
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Line 5 where I am assigning `ip_address` works, however I am not sure if it is the right way to do it. It seems a little ugly and long. I was thinking that maybe I should not put the code block passed to `grep` all on the same line. Or is it even necessary to have 2 separate regexes in there? Can it be done in 1 step?

It also seems strange to me that I need to add `.first` on the end in order to get the IP address string out of the array returned by `grep`. I feel like there is a better way to do this that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are trying to parse arbitrary hosts files why not use the built in IP libraries?

```
require 'ipaddr'
...
ip_address = IPSocket.getaddress(hostname)
```

You could also look at this vagrant add-in: https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater This might work too https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager though I haven't looked at it in depth.

Just a note with your code: you should probably check for commented out lines in your hosts file (at least if it looks anything like mine)

Comment: Well then. That seems like a much better solution. Unfortunately those plugins don't seem do to quite what I want, since I have a pre-existing host file with pre-defined IPs, rather than having the VMs define their own. However, I think using IPSocket.getaddress is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get by with this:

```
ip = File.read(hostfile).match(/^\s*([\d\.]+)\s+\b#{hostname}\s*$/)[1]
```

A more "complete" way might be to do:

```
hosts = File.foreach(hostfile)
  .grep(/^\s*([\d\.:]+)/)
  .map { |line| line.strip.split(/\s+/).reverse }
  .to_h
```

Which gives you a `{ hostname => IP }` hash for everything in the file (IPv6 included for good measure). I.e. you'd just do

```
ip_address = hosts[hostname]
```

to get the IP address.

For your current code:

> It seems a little ugly and long

It is a long line, but you can always break it up. You can chain off of the `end` keyword just as well as off of a `}`, so something like this would help readability:

```
File.foreach(hostfile).grep(/\b#{hostname}\b/) do |m|
  /^([0-9\.]*)\b.*/.match(m)[1]
end.first
```

In the 2nd approach above, I could've used `grep` to both match and map the lines, but I thought it nicer to separate the two.

> It also seems strange to me that I need to add .first on the end in order to get the IP address string out of the array returned by grep

`grep` is being called *for each line*, meaning it'll produce an array of matching lines. Hence why you need `first`. You're basically filtering and mapping every line in the file. After filtering there's (presumably!) only one line left, but it'll still be in an array.

You could use `detect` if you're only interested in the first matching line:

```
line = File.foreach(hostfile).detect { |line| line =~ %r[\b#{hostname}\b] }
```

That'll give you only the line containing the hostname you're looking for (or `nil`), which you can then parse further.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for all the tips and explanation!